# Conceptual View of Single Sign On

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'd like to create a single sign on for multiple websites (sitea.com, siteb.com, sitec.com). All sites are with the same company.  Any database is also with the same company/location. Some are asp.net web apps and some are forums.  I'd like to try and abstract away the SSO so it is not tangled up with any one site.  I've outlined my approach below:

1. user signs into sitea.com, which authenticates user.  A sessionid is created by sitea.com.
2. a cookie is placed on the user's machine with username and sessionid.  The sessionid is inserted into the database centralAuthDB, which all sites have access to.
3. user clicks a link in sitea.com that does SSO to siteb.com (forum).
4. siteb.com retrieves username and sessionid from the cookie.  siteb.com then checks these credentials against centralAuthDB.
5. A match is made with centralAuthDB and the SSO is authenticated.  However, the forum (siteb.com) also has its own database of users.  The username is checked in this database as well and now the user is seamlessly logged into the forum.

Is the above secure and practical?

Should credentials be send to centralAuthDB via webservice?

Will the cookie need some generic name? Then the values for username and sessionid are placed in this cookie?

Comment: At step 4 `siteb` is not going to have access to the cookie from `sitea` (cross site issue)... so that's a bit of a fly in the ointment.

Comment: Yes, as Rudu said, in step 4 you'll have to pass the user and sessionid in the url as parameters.

Comment: Can I ask why you are inventing your own SSO protocol instead of incorporating an existing one? Think of benefits of followind standards rather than being a smart guy which protocols noone else supports. You have at least two interesting possibilities, WS-Federation and OAuth2.

Comment: @Nelson: if the sessionid passed via url, it can still be verified in centralAuthDB.  Does passing through the url this way make it any less secure?

Comment: @Wiktor: incorporating an existing one will a huge investment in time and complexity.  Nothing something I'm looking for.

Comment: First, I don't think investments are "huge". I think you need a week for someone smart to read existing tutorials and be able to follow them (asking for a guidance on a forum like this if necessary). Then, using an enterprise protocol opens the world for you. You can easily integrate other applications, written in different technologies, just because you let them know "follow WS-Federation" or "follow OAuth2". These are all my experiences, we were strugling for 2 years with a home-made SSO protocol just to realize that WS-Federaition was an answer for all our todays and future requirements.

Comment: It's a huge investment to use proven technologies and architectures? I guess you have the utmost confidence in your own ability to do it right the first time without making any mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any SSO, you're going to need a service that takes a credential and generates a secure authentication token. The token must be encrypted so that it cannot be forged; only the authenticating service would be able to decrypt it to check for validity. Then, that token can be passed around to whatever you wish--in a query string, most likely. Cookies are ruled out because they are inaccessible across host names.

As mentioned in the comments on your question, it's wise to investigate pre-existing solutions to this problem. Way smarter guys than you or I have spent thousands of man-hours hashing out all the problems with such systems.

My own personal choice would be OAuth as it's the implementation I'm most familiar with. You might also want to check out how Facebook does authentication for ideas on what, exactly, the token could contain.